# Statistical test for comparing number of clusters in data

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, clustering

I am performing $K$-means clustering on a dataset consisting of $n$ observations and $d$ variables, and I'm trying to determine the optimal number of clusters. Is there a test that can determine the statistical significance of adding another cluster?

I have considered the $F$-test with the following $F$-statistic

$$ F = \frac{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_k-WCSS_{k+1}}{d(k+1)-dk} \Big)}{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_{k+1}}{n-d(k+1)} \Big)} = \frac{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_k-WCSS_{k+1}}{d} \Big)}{ \Big( \frac{WCSS_{k+1}}{n-dk-1} \Big)}$$

where $WCSS_i$ is the within-cluster sum of squares, or inertia, for the model containing $i$ clusters. I obtained the general formula for the $F$-statistic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test#:%7E:text=An%20F%2Dtest%20is%20any,which%20the%20data%20were%20sampled.) under "Regression Problems." In this case, I am treating inertia as a measure of error in the model, and $di$ is the number of parameters in the model with $i$ clusters because each of $i$ clusters has a $d$-dimensional mean vector at its center.

Of course, adding another cluster will often reduce the inertia and never increase it... just as adding another predictor to a linear regression model will often reduce the RSS. The question is whether the reduction observed by adding another cluster is the result of clustering noise or the result of modelling a real pattern in the data. I am assuming a statistically significant p-value would indicate the latter.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What you considered look at: 1. Gap statistic? 2. Dunn index? 3. Silhouette width?

Comment: i am familiar with all of these heuristics that you mentioned. i am specifically wondering if the above approach is a reasonable application of the F-test that can be performed to obtain some more concrete conclusions about adding extra clusters.

Comment: Hmm.. in that case, yes it seems reasonable but I can't see why is "better" than using AIC/BIC directly. You seem to describe a partial $F$-test actually.

Comment: you are correct. it is a partial F-test. I don't think it's possible to compute AIC/BIC for a model resulting from k-means clustering. The way the algorithm proceeds, it doesn't leave room for computing a log likelihood without making some very strong assumptions that likely don't hold. i tried going that route and ultimately decided using the WCSS was less presumptious approach

Comment: As I would think it does"*leave room for computing a log likelihood*" because we can reformulate $k$-meanss as a GMM. Ultimately $k$-means is a special case of a GMM (one with equal and spherical covariance matrices).

Comment: yeah those are the strong assumptions i was talking about. although, i suppose if i'm already making those assumptions by using k-means in the first place, then i might as well continue making them to compute a log likelihood.

Comment: That's how I see it too. (+1)

Comment: yeah, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I am glad I could help. Maybe I will write these up as a bit of an answer in the next couple of days so we help out our "unanswered questions" ratio! :) Best of luck going forward!